# Intuitive understanding of showing that $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ in $C^k(A)$, A open has local max in $A$.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $A\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be open and $f:A\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be $C^k(A)$. Suppose there is an $x_0$ in $A$ so that $$Df(x_0)x=D^2f(x_0)(x,x)=\dots=D^{k-1}(x_0)(x,\ldots,x)=0$$
and $$D^k(x_0)(x,\ldots,x)<0\;\;\forall\, x\in\mathbb{R}^n\backslash\{0\}$$
Show that $f$ has a local max at $x_0$

**My understanding:**
So if we put a closed ball $B=\overline{B}(x_0,\delta)$ in $A$, we can use Taylor's theorem to say that for all $x\in B$
$$f(x)=f(x_0)+\frac{1}{k!}D^{k}f(\alpha)(x-x_0,\ldots,x-x_0),\quad\alpha=x_0+t(x-x_0),\;t\in(0,1) \tag{1}$$
I know that I want to use the continuity of $D^kf$ to show that I can get close enough to $x_0$ so that $\frac{1}{k!}D^{k}f(\alpha)(x-x_0,\ldots,x-x_0)$ is negative. Originally, I just argued that we can shrink $\delta$ so that we will have $D^k(\alpha)(x-x_0,\ldots)$ negative as well by continuity, but apprarently that's not obvious.

According to friends, in my original approach I glossed over the fact that as $x-x_0$ gets small, $D^kf(\alpha)$ can get arbitrarily close to $0$ from below while simultaneously
$||D^k(x_0)-D^k(\alpha)||$ gets small in the operator norm (or $|D^k(x_0)(x-x_0,\ldots)-D^k(\alpha)(x-x_0,\ldots)|$ gets small if you prefer). The argument they proposed went as follows:

For $x\in S=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n:|x|=1\}$, $S$ compact implies  $D^kf(x_0)(x,\ldots,x)$ must have a max $M<0$ at $y\in S$. So given $x\neq 0$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, we have 
$$D^kf(x_0)(x,\ldots,x)=|x|^kD^kf(x_0)\left(\frac{x}{|x|},\ldots,\frac{x}{|x|}\right)\leq|x|^kM < 0\tag{2}$$
Let $\frac{|M|}{2}>\epsilon>0$. We can shrink $\delta$ so that $|x_0-\alpha|<\delta$ gives $||D^kf(x_0)-D^k(\alpha)||<\epsilon$. Then from $(1)$ allowing some abuse of notation, 
\begin{align*}
f(x)-f(x_0)&=\frac{1}{k!}D^{k}f(x_0)(x-x_0)+\frac{1}{k!}D^{k}f(\alpha)(x-x_0)-\frac{1}{k!}D^{k}f(x_0)(x-x_0)\\
&\leq \frac{1}{k!}\left(|x|^kM+D^{k}f(\alpha)(x-x_0)-D^{k}f(x_0)(x-x_0)\right)\quad\text{from $(2)$}\\
&<\frac{1}{k!}|x|^k\left(M+\epsilon\right)\\
&<\frac{1}{k!}\delta^k\frac{M}{2}<0
\end{align*}

**My confusion** comes in understanding why this is needed. I see that their argument is very explicit in showing that $f(x)<f(x_0)$ and is in that sense better. But the only reason that I can articulate why this is necessary is that there is some kind of competition as $x\rightarrow x_0$ between the linear operators $D^kf(x_0)$ and $D^kf(x)$ by continuity and $D^kf(x)$ possibly getting arbirtrarily close to $0$, and we need to show that $D^kf(x)(x-x_0)$ will be between $D^kf(x_0)(x-x_0)$ and $0$ rather explicitly. But why isn't it obvious by continuity other than being a little obfuscated by being in $\mathbb{R}^n$? Is there a counterexample?

Answer (score 1):

Note that $k$ is necessarily even.

Since you are working in finite dimensional space, the theorem of Weierstraß about maxima on compact sets applies and thus there is some $c>0$ such that
$$
D^kf(x_0)[v^k]\le -c·\|v\|^k
$$
where $-c$ is the maximum of the left side as a function of $v$ on the unit sphere $\{v:\|v\|=1\}$.

Then by continuity of $D^kf$ there is some $δ>0$ such that
$$
D^kf(x)[v^k]\le -\frac{c}2·\|v\|^k
$$
for all $x\in B(x_0,δ)$ and your first argument about the Taylor expansion applies.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the continuity of $D^kf$. Note that the homogeneous polynomial $p(X):=D^kf(x_0).(X,\ldots,X)$ is continuous and $<0$ on $S^{n-1}$, hence satisfies
$$p(X)\leq-\mu<0\qquad(X\in S^{n-1})\ .$$
By Taylor's theorem we therefore have
$$f(x_0+X)-f(x_0)={1\over k!}\,p(X)+o(|X|^k)\leq-{|X|^k\over k!}\bigl(\mu+o(1)\bigr)\qquad(X\to0)\ .$$
Here the right hand side is $<0$ for sufficiently small $|X|>0$.